# Cambiar border-bottom-color en input de Material Design

Tags: css, material-design

Estoy intentando modificar el color del borde inferior de un input de la librería material design que ofrece Angular ([Enlace](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)) por el blanco y no hay manera. He probado de editar el md-input-container y clases internas pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<md-toolbar>
    <md-icon>account_box</md-icon>
    <span>Usuarios</span>
    <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
    <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput #filter type="search">
        <span mdSuffix>
            <md-icon>search</md-icon>
        </span>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado modificando `.mat-input-ripple`?

Comment: Sí, pero no lo modifica.

Comment: ¿Como lo has hecho? [Acá una demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sPQb9BoYsMKl0w05nEPe?p=preview) (ver index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente la clase de css que quieres modificar es "mat-input-underline"

lo que puedes hacer para cambiar el color es hacer lo siguiente:

```
.mat-input-underline{
    color: blue;
}
```

Esto cambiará el borde inferior a color azul, adicionalmente si quieres cambiar el color del borde cuando el input tiene focus, debes cambiar lo siguiente:

```
.mat-input-ripple {
    background-color: green;
}
```

debo aclarar que estas lineas de css cambiarían todos tus inputs a esos colores, si solo quieres que un input tenga ese color debes crear el selector correcto (probablemente con el ID).

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, necesitaba utilizar el selector >>> para cambiarlo forzadamente.